# App Resources not working using Static Resource / Static Extension

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Good day! I am using Prism 7.2 along with Xamarin.Forms 4.2 and I am trying to use an external asset for fonts. I have defined them on my app resources and used it on my xaml code, however, when I try to use the static extension `{x:Static}`  for the value of `Text` combined with `Style` that also has a static resource extension `{StaticResource}` the text doesn't appear to be working. Below is the code that I am using.

```
 <prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="LineAwesomeFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="line-awesome.ttf#LineAwesome"/>
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="lineawesome"/>
        </OnPlatform>
        <Style x:Key="LineAwesomeFonts"
               TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="{StaticResource LineAwesomeFontFamily }" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
```

Calling it in a view

```
<Label Text="{x:Static fonts:LineAwesomeFonts.Adjust}"
       Style="{StaticResource LineAwesomeFonts}"
       TextColor="Black">
</Label>
```

If I try in a different way

```
 <Label x:Name="testLabel"
        FontSize="28" TextColor="Black">
        <Label.FontFamily>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="line-awesome.ttf#LineAwesome"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Label.FontFamily>
  </Label>
```

and call the testLabel on `xaml.cs` for it to have a value it will work.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? There are no errors to be found when it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it is my fault.

```
 public App(IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) : base(platformInitializer)
 {}


 protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
     InitializeComponent(); //moved this away from App constructor and put it here
     NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Test");
 }
```

Though it was weird because my `InitializeComponent();` on the other project was on the `App` Constructor and resources was working as intended.